# Authentication stopped working for github after creating a new repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have both the private key installed on my local machine and the public key installed on github. This is verified b.c. I can use another repository just fine.

Key appears to work fine for the account:

[image]

However after initializing my new repo, adding files, comiting, and pushing ... I get strange behavior.

It asks for my username and password ( which I know had been deprecated ) and then tells me authentication has failed.

How do I "alert" the new repository to use the already installed SSH key pair?

Oddly, I am not getting anything back when I do a

> ssh-add -l

per [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58969/how-to-list-keys-added-to-ssh-agent-with-ssh-add).  I'm not even sure how my other repo is authenticated at this point.

I can verify ssh by

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

which shows SSH is setup correctly.

The file named config in .git has not been modified but here it is:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/caaker/frame-config.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

Comment: it looks like your .gitconfig file is not configured globally. maybe your ssh key configured only one repository

Comment: I restarted my computer and the terminal, and still no go, can't figure out why one repo works and not the other.  Verifed SSH is working per updated Question.

Comment: `notepad %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig` look at it is there any configuration for ssh? if there isn't, most probably your ssh configuration is in the .git directory of of your repository and there is a .config file in there it is the locally configurated remote credentials here

Comment: I added the default `config` file in the .git directory.  Is that relevant?

Comment: I did find an odd entry in the working repository but can not determine what config file it is in.

Comment: `credential.helper=osxkeychain`

Answer (score 2):

You are using HTTPS URL instead of SSH URL in your `.git/config`. You should replace:

`url = https://github.com/caaker/frame-config.git`

with
`url = git@github.com:caaker/frame-config.git`.

Alternatively, you can set it using `git remote set-url <remote_name> <SSH-URL>` , in this case: `git remote set-url github git@github.com:caaker/frame-config.git`

See https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#about-remote-repositories

Comment: If you clone the repository using the HTTPS URL, the remote `url` will be set as HTTPS, whereas if you clone using the SSH URL, the remote `url` will be set as SSH